# Confusion with Gnuplot postscript terminal (CORRECTION : This is an issue with Mac Preview)

Tags: image, macos, terminal, gnuplot

I am confused about the how to get the postscript terminal to replicate a similar figure to the png terminal.

Here is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env gnuplot

#set terminal png 
#set output 'test.png'
set terminal postscript eps enhanced
set output 'test.eps'

set palette defined (0 1.0 1.0 1.0, 1e-19 0.0 0.0 1.0, 1 1.0 0.0 0.0)
set cbrange [0:9]
plot 'test.dat' u 1:2:($3 > 0 ? $3 : 0) with image
```

Here is my data file:

```
1.0  1.0  4.0
1.0  2.0  7.0
1.0  3.0  9.0
2.0  1.0  6.0
2.0  2.0  8.0
2.0  3.0  2.0
3.0  1.0  8.0
3.0  2.0  1.0
3.0  3.0  0.0
```

When I plot the data  using the png terminal the edges between the cells are crisp.  When I use the postscript terminal, the edges of the cells use a color gradient to transition between the colors of the cells.

Question: Is there a way to make the eps terminal so that it does not have a gradient of colors at the edges of the cells and replicates the crisp edges of the png image?

Comment: Using your test data I can't reproduce this (tested with 4.4.3 and 4.6.5 on Windows). Note, that in general you should separate blocks with different x-values by a single empty line when plotting with `image`.

Comment: That is unfortunate.  I am using Mac OSX 10.6.8, Gnuplot Version 4.6 patchlevel 4.  I tried separating the data as you suggested and I still get the same effect.

Comment: Uh, if I remember correctly, quite recently someone else had a similar problem due to the Mac Preview. Could you check the eps file with different viewers?

Comment: Oh man, that is weird.  You are spot on. If I convert test.eps to test.pdf and then open test.pdf with Preview it looks correct.  I imported test.eps into a LaTex file, and the pdf generated by TexShop, when viewed with Preview looks like garbage.  When the TexShop generated pdf is viewed with Adobe Acrobat, it looks correct.

Comment: Effectively you have an embedded bitmap 3 pixels high and 3 pixels wide. I guess, Preview tries to smooth this bitmap...

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Mac's Preview is having difficulty with dealing with the eps image.  When viewed in TexShop generated pdf with Adobe Acrobat it is correct.  Thank you Christoph.