# How to improve lines quality of a heat map

Tags: gnuplot

I have plotted the matrix of numbers of this file

[pher-of-1365.txt](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xil30t8lgvca00g/pher-of-1365.txt?dl=0)

with this code

```
set encoding iso_8859_1
set term postscript eps enhanced color size 4.7in,4in
set xlabel "longitude"
set ylabel "latitude"
set output "test0.eps"
set size square 
set title "Pheromones" font "Helvetica, 16"
set autoscale fix
set key
set yrange [:] reverse
set view map
splot 'pher-of-1365.txt' matrix with image
```

Which produces this plot:

[image]

The quality is not bad but the lines look blurred.

Is there a way to improve the clarity of the lines in the image?

Regards

Comment: To me this looks like the program you use to convert the eps fie into a bitmap image is using some sort of smoothening/antialiasing. For example, I see the same effect when viewing your eps file in Preview on MacOS, but not when converting it to a bitmap file in ImageMagick.  What viewer are you using?

Comment: @user8153 Thanks for commenting. I use Mac OSX Preview which converts the eps to pdf. The text looks fine but the image loses quality.

Comment: Preview is known for these issues, see for example [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/246755/viewing-postscript-or-pdf-on-os-x-aliasing-issues).

Comment: Also releated: [Confusion with Gnuplot postscript terminal (CORRECTION : This is an issue with Mac Preview)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25736904/2604213)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use can try to use a different `plot` statement, and tweak the point size to get a sharper image. I used your script with the `pdf` terminal, in 4 different cases:

```
set terminal pdf size 12,12
set output "test0.pdf"
set encoding iso_8859_1

set xlabel "longitude"
set ylabel "latitude"
set size square
set format cb "%2.0t{/Symbol \327}10^{%L}"
set autoscale fix
unset key
set yrange [:] reverse
set view map

set multiplot layout 2,2

set title "plot with image"
splot 'pher-of-1365.txt' matrix with image

set title "plot with points pointtype 5 pointsize 0.45 palette"
splot 'pher-of-1365.txt' matrix with points pointtype 5 pointsize 0.45 palette

set title "plot with points pointtype 5 pointsize 0.25 palette"
splot 'pher-of-1365.txt' matrix with points pointtype 5 pointsize 0.25 palette

set title "plot with points pointtype 3 pointsize 1.25 palette"
splot 'pher-of-1365.txt' matrix with points pointtype 3 pointsize 1.25 palette
```

Resulting in:

[image: output]

Things to note:

- The only reason the solution on the upper right panel works is because your plotting area is squared, and I used `pointtype 5` (filled squares). Then, be tweaking the `pointsize` param you can fill the entire area. Note what happens on the bottom panels, when I change the size and type on the points.
- As mentioned in the comments, the **right** way of doing this is using `image`, since it will figure things our by itself, and fill in the plotting area.

Comment: is much sharper. Thank you. Is ther any way to matain the sharpness and shoften the pixels?

Comment: You mean making the lines narrower? I think that is not possible, because it has to do with the actual sampling (spacing) of the dataset. Try to change the `ps 0.30` value to something like 0.15 and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Note that this solution requires the point size to match the size of a grid cell exactly, whereas `plot ... with image` does that automatically.

Comment: @user8153 Yes, you're absolutely correct. It does look a bit better in this particular case, but not a robust solution at all!

Comment: @ViniciusPlacco Thank you. I understand now what the problem is.