# Label inside a splot with a symbol or point

Tags: gnuplot

In the plot of the question

[How to improve lines quality of a heat map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49679757/how-to-improve-lines-quality-of-a-heat-map)

(code and data are at this link) I would like to mark points into the drawing with a symbol. Since the plot represents a map it could be the typical google map dot location or any other symbol, for example, a flag, a star or a square.
I have seen examples that use `set label`at a position. How could I label the plot with a symbol mark?

Comment: You can also use `pointtype` with characters, see last example at http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_svg_5.2/lines_arrows.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one of the built-in gnuplot point types works for you, you can simply add another line to your plot command like

```
plot '-' notitle with points pt 7 ps 3
1 2
e
```

As pointed out below you can also use a font character for that purpose:

```
plot '-' u 1:2:("{/Symbol \247}") notitle with labels
1 2
e
```

A list of postscript character codes is [here](http://ayapin-film.sakura.ne.jp/Gnuplot/Docs/ps_guide.pdf). In both cases you can of course keep the coordinates in a separate data file as well (rather than using inline data).

You can also do things like

```
set object circle at 1,2 size 0.5
```

---

### Example

The linked question uses `splot`, which is not necessary for a two-dimensional graph. Here is an example, using the linked data:

```
set terminal pngcairo size 800,600
set output "test0.png"
set encoding iso_8859_1

set xlabel "longitude"
set ylabel "latitude"
set size square
set format cb "%2.0t{/Symbol \327}10^{%L}"
set autoscale fix
unset key
set yrange [:] reverse


plot 'pher-of-1365.txt' matrix with image, \
'-' with points pointtype 7 pointsize 2 lc "yellow"
20 40
e

set output
```

[image]

Comment: I also cannot get ZapfDingbats to work when using Mac Preview software. However, if you open the `.eps` file using, e.g. linux `evince`, the symbols will be rendered correctly.

Comment: @user8153 Thank you to answer. I have tried the first two answers but gnuplot complains about the 1 2 e lines of data. How can I test the `plot '-' notitle with points pt 7 ps 3` and the `plot '-' u 1:2:("{/Symbol \247}") notitle with labels`?. The third `set object...` does not show any circle. Surely I am missing something, please, may I ask you how to set a symbol into my referenced plot?

Comment: @user8153 It works If I call gnuplot from the Terminal and try the command above, but not into the gnuplot script.

Comment: I added an example. What error message do you get from gnuplot?

Comment: @user8153 I was doing it wrong, split line and after a plot command. Thank you.